# Proving Singmaster's Conjecture: Can you prove there are finitely many solutions of $\binom{n+x-1}{n}=y$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

### $n,x,y \in\mathbb{N},  \binom{n+x-1}{n}=y$

I am completely out of my depth.  What I am really asking is how can you prove there is an upper bound on the number of pairs (n, x) to satisfy an arbitrary y?

This has probably already been discovered as a simplification of Singmaster's conjecture, but finding the upper bound of the numbers of these pairs is also finding the upper bound of the number of multiplicities of an arbitrary entry of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: The existence of an upper bound is really easy, in fact $y$ canot appear after the $y+1$-th row and hence $$\left|\left\{n,x\in\mathbb{N}\big /  \binom{n+x-1}{n}=y\right\}\right|<y^2 $$

Comment: I'm missing something.  Why is it $y^2$?

Comment: because there are less than $y^2$ numbers in the first $y$ rows of **Pascal's triangle**  (which may possibly be equal to $y$, it's a big approximation). Actually it's not $y^2$ but $y(y+1)/2$ and even that you can subtract the number of ones which is **2y** .

Comment: Although, if the arbitrary y tends to infinity, so does the bound, so is there any way to have the bound at some constant like the conjecture would state , as in:
$\left|\left\{n,x \in\mathbb{N}  \binom{n+x-1}{n}=y\right\}\right|\leq \mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: Proving that $\left|\left\{n,x \in\mathbb{N}  \binom{n+x-1}{n}=y\right\}\right|\leq \mathcal{O}(1)$ is equivalent to Singmaster's conjecture. And it's a conjecture meaning that we don't know how to prove it yet !!, if you have a solution it would be a very amazing result and you can publish it !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Except for $\binom{n}{0}=\binom{n}{n}=1$ we have $\binom{n}{k}\geq n$.